# Howto set Anchor in NSPreferencePane for AppleScript

Tags: macos, cocoa, applescript

I'd like to access a certain tabView item in my own pref pane via AppleScript like that:

```
tell application "System Preferences"
    reveal anchor "Firewall" of pane id "com.apple.preference.security"
end tell
```

Is there a way to set the anchor names in Interface Builder (or in code) that I can access a certain "anchor" in my own pref pane via AppleScript like in the com.apple.preference.security pref pane???

Answer (score 1):

This works...

```
tell application "System Preferences"
    activate
    tell pane id "com.apple.preference.security" to reveal anchor "Firewall"
end tell
```

Comment: hi,thanks for your answer, maybe my question was too unspecific. I want to add that feature to my own pref pane and I don't know where in Interface Builder or in my Code I have to assign the names for the anchors.